# Firefox Responsive Select Icon Disappearing

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have an issue with the Firefox select element where when I shrink the width to just the button icon, the icon will disappear when zooming out.

Open in Firefox and zoom out to 90%
https://jsfiddle.net/uqLvphwu/6/

Html

```
  <select>
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <option>test1</option>
    <option>test2</option>
    <option>test3</option>
    <option>test4</option>
    <option>test5</option>
    <option>test6</option>
  </select>
```

CSS

```
select {
    height: 41px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

This seems to be a bug with Firefox's responsiveness but wanted to see if anyone had a work around with css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert `px` into `em` or even better `rem`. Both `em` and `rem` are scalable and therefor work better with responsive websites. The example doesn't completely fix your problem but it's a start.

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;  
}
select {
    height: 4rem;
    width: 1.5rem;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    border-radius: 0.8rem;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
  <select>
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <option>test1</option>
    <option>test2</option>
    <option>test3</option>
    <option>test4</option>
    <option>test5</option>
    <option>test6</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Still seems to disappear at 70% zoom but definitely a improvement and makes my edge case even more rare at this point. I'll probably use this for now. Thanks

Comment: @mattfetz The real `rem` size needs to be adjusted for your case. If you really want to use `rem` you might need to get some more information on how to calculate them.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to just set the width of the select to use percentages (like 3.5%)